# Identifying 6 pin SMD K273-7

Tags: mosfet

This is a smd piece on an ASUS ROG Maximus XI Hero (Wi-Fi) that doesn't have working on-board Wi-Fi. I cannot for the life of me find this what I believe is a mosfet. It has three pins on each side of it, top left and bottom right are both ground. The top of the mosfet reads 'K273' on the first line and a line below it in the same orientation with just the number 7 under the 3 on the first line. The top left ground is directly above the 3 on the first line, whereas the bottom right ground just has a dot next to it printed on the top. Would love to be able to find a replacement as the only ones I have on donor boards are too high resistance and the card is still undetected by the system. Thanks for any help!

[image: One has been broken off and the other is intact.]

Comment: what is the purpose of the photograph?

Comment: I figured I'd add one for a general layout. It's too grainy to make out what's on it so I put in text as best I could what's on it. Although I guess that's deterring people from commenting. It's so small the only way I'm able to read what's on it is with my bare eyes and a flashlight at an angle.